# Question about Range of BLEU

Tags: computational-linguistics, machine-translation, evaluation-metrics

I read that range of BLEU is 0 to 1.(from ["BLEU" page on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLEU))

But i found some paper says like

> "we achieve a significant gain of **5.0 BLEU points** over
>   non-attentional systems that already incorporate known techniques such
>   as dropout"

Does "5.0 BLEU points" mean 0.5 BLEU?
or BLEU range is not 0 to 1 and actually exceed 1?

Answer (score 3):

The BLEU score is between 0 and 1, but is sometime expressed as a percentage, i.e. ranging from 0 to 100%.

E.g. http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.SupportTools#ntoc5 returns a score between 0 and 100 ([code](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/generic/multi-bleu.perl)).

Misc:

- Original BLEU paper: http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P02-1040.pdf
- Some technical issues in BLEU: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1268